# Kinematic, motion in 2D

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

If the kinetic energy at maximum height is 2/5 the kinetic energy at half the maximum height, find the angle of projection.

In other words: K.E. at H(max) = 0.4*K.E. at 0.5*H(max)

I got 60 degrees, however, my teacher told me that the answer is 30 degrees. Please solve it for me so I can see where I went wrong.

Well here's my edit:

Consider u to be the velocity at H(max)
Consider v to be the velocity at half of H(max)
Consider c to be initial velocity given 
Consider @ to be angle projected at
sqr() means square root

u^2 = 0.4v^2

u is obviously c*cos(@)
v I found to be: sqr((0.5u^2)(1+(cos(@))^2)

Using this, I substituted into the previous equation and solved to attain:
cos@ = 0.5

So.... That gives me 60 degrees. Am I right? Or is there some sort of catch?

Comment: No, show your solution first, so that we can see where you went wrong.

Comment: @Gummy you are right i also got 60 degree.

Comment: Please read the site's homework policy and act accordingly. That's the point that @Bernhard is trying to make.

Comment: If you'd really act according to the _home-work_ policy of this site then perhaps you will have to delete the question. Because acc. to their policy one can only ask about the concept not _how to solve this_.

Comment: @user31782 I understand you are pissed for some reason. I have also been a victim of ''silent downvotes'' (which you keep ''countering'') in one of my answers, but I still think that the homework policy of the site is rational. God bless you, kid, in terms of the proposal that I saw on your flair, even though I'm precisely the kind of a person who would stand eliminated by your mission statement.

Comment: Very sorry for such an outbreak. I am new to this site and was unaware of its policies... Sorry

Comment: @ Gummy bears - Please don't be so concerned. You have edited your question accordingly, and i don't think the moderators will have an issue now. +1 for the effort and acting responsibly. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Velocity at top point is totally horizontal,$ v\cos x$
velocity at half the top height is
 $V=\sqrt{ {(v\sin x-gt)}^{2}-{(v\cos x)}^{2} } $
where
$x$ is the angle of projection
$g$ is acceleration due to gravity
$t$ is time elapsed at half of max height
$v$ is the velocity of projection

Equate ${v\cos x}^{2}= 2/5* {V}^{2} $